# how to apply different backgraound colors for particular selected columns in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to apply different colors for each column in my XSLT stylesheet but I could not find a satisfying solution.

Here is my xsl code:

```
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:template match ="records">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="list">
            <fo:region-body></fo:region-body>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="list">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-body>

                         <xsl:for-each select="./list">
                            <fo:table-row background-color="rgb(192,192,192)">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./item">
                             <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                              <fo:block font-family="monospace"
font-size="12pt"  color="green"
wrap-option="no-wrap"   padding="5pt" 
space-before="5pt"  space-after="5pt">
<xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my data that comes from xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<records>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Column 1</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Column 2</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Column 3</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Column 4</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Column 5</val>
    </item>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Value 1</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Value 2</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Value 3</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Value 4</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Value 5</val>
    </item>
</list>
</records>
```

Now, in the output the table cells of value1 and column1 should be of the same color, value2 and column 2 should be of the same color and so on. But every column should be in a different color.

Can any one help with the changes I need to make in my xsl code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not hard-code your `color` attribute. Instead, check what element you are looking at within an `xsl:choose` and then assign a value to the `color` attribute respectively.

Of course, "Column 1" might not be the actual name in your XML data and you'd have to replace this:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(./val,'1')">
```

with another condition that can tell your `item` elements apart. If the coloring depends on position only, use `position()` as suggested by @Tomalak.

**Full stylesheet**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:template match ="records">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
       <fo:simple-page-master master-name="list">
           <fo:region-body></fo:region-body>
       </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>

   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="list">
       <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
           <fo:block>
               <fo:table>
                   <fo:table-body>

                        <xsl:for-each select="./list">
                           <fo:table-row background-color="rgb(192,192,192)">
                           <xsl:for-each select="./item">
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                             <fo:block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap"   padding="5pt" space-before="5pt"  space-after="5pt">
                                <xsl:attribute name="background-color">
                                   <xsl:choose>
                                      <xsl:when test="contains(./val,'1')">
                                         <xsl:text>green</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="contains(./val,'2')">
                                         <xsl:text>red</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="contains(./val,'3')">
                                         <xsl:text>orange</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="contains(./val,'4')">
                                         <xsl:text>blue</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:otherwise>
                                         <xsl:text>black</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:otherwise>
                                   </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="val"/>
                             </fo:block>
                               </fo:table-cell>
                               </xsl:for-each>
                           </fo:table-row>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                   </fo:table-body>
               </fo:table>
           </fo:block>
       </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With FOP 1.0, the output looks like:

[image]

**EDIT**: Now the background color changes instead of the font color.

Comment: here each columns background color should be different and the text should be black in all columns.. i have added a pictorial representation of my reqiured output. and the first row should not reside in the table it should be like some heading. can you please change as per requirement. thank you

Comment: thank you but still the cell border color= black was missing in the output??

Comment: No, background-color="black" is not missing from the XSLT output. Did you look at @Tomalak's solution, too? It's a more flexible solution, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
>
    <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="list">
                    <fo:region-body></fo:region-body>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="list">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="records" />
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="records">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="list" />
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="records/list">
        <fo:table-row background-color="rgb(192,192,192)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="records/list/item">
        <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
            <fo:block 
                font-family="monospace"
                font-size="12pt"
                wrap-option="no-wrap"
                padding="5pt"
                space-before="5pt"
                space-after="5pt"
            >
                <xsl:call-template name="cell-color" />
                <xsl:value-of select="val" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cell-color">
        <xsl:attribute name="color">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">green</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 2">blue</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 3">red</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 4">yellow</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 5">brown</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>black</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you

```
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <layout-master-set>
    <simple-page-master master-name="list">
      <region-body/>
    </simple-page-master>
  </layout-master-set>
  <page-sequence master-reference="list">
    <flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <block>
        <table>
          <table-body>
            <table-row background-color="rgb(192,192,192)">
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="green">Column 1</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="blue">Column 2</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="red">Column 3</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="yellow">Column 4</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="brown">Column 5</block>
              </table-cell>
            </table-row>
            <table-row background-color="rgb(192,192,192)">
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="green">Value 1</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="blue">Value 2</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="red">Value 3</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="yellow">Value 4</block>
              </table-cell>
              <table-cell text-align="center">
                <block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" color="brown">Value 5</block>
              </table-cell>
            </table-row>
          </table-body>
        </table>
      </block>
    </flow>
  </page-sequence>
</root>
```

Notes

- This solution does not use `<xsl:for-each>`. You should generally try to avoid it.
- Break your code into several templates and use `<xsl:apply-templates>`.
- You can create attributes (like `color`) in a separate template.
- Using `<xsl:call-template>` does not affect the value of `position()`.
- Declare `xmlns:fo` at the stylesheet level.

There is a lot of pointless duplication in your cell definitions. I'm sure XSL:FO has a way to avoid that. Try to produce output that is less duplicated.